# How to update record on another model (trigger) in google app maker sql?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I want to make a trigger that update another record where specific field contains a string in google app maker sql. How to do that? help me please.

Here is my first table called "User" (Id,Code,Fname,Lname), when I insert something there, I want to update another table called "History" (Id, User, dateUpdate, *Counter*). Here is my script on 'onAfterCreate' event on "User" events.

```
var query = app.models.History.newQuery();
query.filters.User._equals = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
var records = query.run();
//console.log("Found " + records.length + " Users.");
if(records.length > 0){
  var nilBaru = Math.round(records[0].Count)+1;
  //I want to get "History" field that contains specific string and if exist i want to update it's records.

}else{
     var sejarah = app.models.History.newRecord();
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
    var update = new Date();

    sejarah.User = userEmail;
    sejarah.Update = update;
    sejarah.Count = 1;

    app.saveRecords([sejarah]);
   }
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Oh i solve it by myself.. hahaha

```
var query = app.models.History.newQuery();
query.filters.User._equals = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
var records = query.run();
var id = records[0]._key;
//console.log("Found " + records.length + " Users.");
if(records.length > 0){
  var nilBaru = Math.round(records[0].Count)+1;

 var record = app.models.History.getRecord(id);
  record.Count = nilBaru;
  app.saveRecords([record]);
}else{
     var sejarah = app.models.History.newRecord();
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
    var update = new Date();

    sejarah.User = userEmail;
    sejarah.Update = update;
    sejarah.Count = 1;

    app.saveRecords([sejarah]);
   }
```